# CollectionView layout doesn't refresh until scroll

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

The best way to demonstrate my problem is with the video below:

http://foffer.dk/collectionview.mp4

As you can see, my collectionView doesn't update it's layout to correctly display the items until I start scrolling. I'm using a separate collectionViewFlowLayout model. Here is my code:

CollectionViewFlowLayout.m:

```
@implementation CollectionViewFlowLayout

- (void)prepareLayout {

    CGFloat halfWidth = self.collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2;
    CGFloat halfHeight = self.collectionView.bounds.size.height / 2;


    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(halfWidth, halfHeight);
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 0;

}


// indicate that we want to redraw as we scroll
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

my PhotosCollectionViewController (I've left out the standart collectionView stuff as I didn't think it is important to this issue, let me know if it is and I will post it):

```
-(instancetype)init {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[CollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];


    return (self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout]);
}

-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [self.collectionView registerClass:[FOFPhotoCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photo"];
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    CGFloat bottomLayoutGuide =  self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, bottomLayoutGuide, 0);

}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
```

Do I need to call invalidateLayout somewhere? I can't seem to figure out where to implement that method. `[self.collectionView invalidateLayout]` doesn't work.

Could someone get me on the right track here?

Thanks in advance
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out I had it set up all wrong. As [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW1) from apple says:

> Before you start building custom layouts, consider whether doing so is
>   really necessary.
>
> The UICollectionViewFlowLayout class provides a
>   significant amount of behavior that has already been optimized for
>   efficiency and that can be adapted in several ways to achieve many
>   different types of standard layouts. The only times to consider
>   implementing a custom layout are in the following situations:
>
> The layout you want looks nothing like a grid or a line-based breaking
>   layout (a layout in which items are placed into a row until it’s full,
>   then continue on to the next line until all items are placed) or
>   necessitates scrolling in more than one direction.
>
> You want to change all of the cell positions frequently enough that it would be more work
>   to modify the existing flow layout than to create a custom layout.

And my layout config is really simple. So I was overcomplicating it.